# How can I install intel Cilk for C/C++ parallel programming on windows 10?

Tags: c, windows, parallel-processing, cilk-plus

I would like to experiment with intel's Cilk extension for C/C++ parallel programming but I am having a hard time figuring out how to install it on Windows. I tried consulting the [official site](https://www.cilkplus.org/) but I couldn't find any Windows oriented guide. Switching to Linux is not convenient right now and I would prefer to leave it as a last resort.

I also tried to get a free trial version of Parallel Studio, but apparently it does not support CILK anymore.

If someone could guide me step-by-step, I would be very grateful.

I use Code Blocks, which includes the gnu gcc compiler.

Comment: Have you tried [downloading](https://www.cilkplus.org/download#block-views-cilk-tools-block-1) the Windows installer and running it?

Comment: @ForceBru thank you for your comment. Please correct me if I am wrong but, in case you are referring to the  Intel Cilk Plus SDK, it merely provides tools which facilitate the debugging/code improvement, not the actual silk libraries, headers etc for C/C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(To start with, excuse me, I've never used Cilk personally).

First of all, it's deprecated:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cilk#Obsolescence
- https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-cilk-plus/topic/745556

If you want to try it with **GCC**, you need to get GCC (perhaps, versions from 4.9 to 8.0; support deprecated in 7.1 and removed in 8.1) compiled with Cilk support.
And then it should work in a very simple way, e.g.:

> ```
> $ gcc -fcilkplus -lcilkrts <OTHER_FLAGS> mycode1.c
> $ g++ -fcilkplus -lcilkrts <OTHER_FLAGS> mycode2.cpp
> ```

(I've tried to add these flags when compiling a non-Cilk C source on my **Debian** 9 GNU/Linux (amd64) system, and it seems to work; `libcilkrts5` package seems to get installed there along with GCC 6.3.0, by default).

Here is a list of popular binary GCC builds:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/install/binaries.html

Unfortunately, most GCC binaries for MS Windows I can find come without Cilk enabled;
e.g., I didn't find it in the following packages:

- http://codeblocks.org/downloads/binaries
- https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/

At least, it can be found in **Cygwin** (it has `gcc-cilkplus` & `libcilkrts5` in its package list):

- https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html

Alternatively, you can probably try **Intel C++ Compiler** (no experience with that, sorry).

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cilk#Intel_Cilk_Plus
- https://www.cilkplus.org/build-gcc-cilkplus

Comment: (*A few months later...*)

I know it's been a while and I apologize for neglecting to mention it here but... Cygwin did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Cilk is alive and kicking at MIT as [OpenCilk](https://cilk.mit.edu/)

You can either build it or even download a binary, but only linux, Mac or source is offered